# Trying to use SoftLayer_Network_Service_VPN_Overrides with the createObjects method and the REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to use SoftLayer_Network_Service_VPN_Overrides with the `createObjects` method and the REST API to add VPN overrides. My account is set to `manual` for VPN access. I am trying something like this:

```
curl -X POST -d @subnetadd.json https://$SL_API_USER:$SL_API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides/createObjects.xml
```

where `subnetadd.json` looks something like this:

```
{
    "parameters" : [
        {
            "subnetId" : 123456,
            "userId" : 123456
        }
    ]
}
```

When I have valid entries in there I get a false in the xml that is returned. Do I need to frame my parameters differently or the number of parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides::createObjects](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides/createObjects) method receives an array of SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides objects, try the following modification:

```
curl -X POST -d @subnetadd.json https://$SL_API_USER:$SL_API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Ser‌​vice_Vpn_Overrides/createObjects.json

{  
   "parameters":[  
      [  
         {  
            "subnetId":123456,
            "userId":123456
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

**Note**: If you are using .json in the payload, the return type should be the same.

Comment: Still returning false

Comment: Instead to retrieves .xml try with .json, because you are using a json in the payload curl -X POST -d @subnetadd.json https://$SL_API_USER:$SL_API_KEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Service_Vpn_Overrides/createObjects.json